# How do I make gnuplot remember turned off plot lines when calling replot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have this gnuplot script where I update the graph every second:

```
set term qt noraise
plot "DetumbData"  u 1:3 w lp t "X" , "CoilOff" u 1:3 w lp t "X " , "mctr" u 1:3 w lp t "X" , 0.0015 title "+ Threshold",-0.0015 title "- Threshold"

while(1) {
        replot
        pause 1
}
```

In the plot window, if I click the legend to disable a particular plot line, it gets reenabled when `replot` is executed. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Which gnuplot version? Works fine for me with version 5.0.6 both with `qt` and `wxt` terminal.

Comment: `G N U P L O T
 Version 5.0 patchlevel 3    last modified 2016-02-21 `

Comment: I am guessing the  `6` in your `5.0.6` is the patchlevel. How do I update on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the comment from Christoph, I compiled the latest `gnuplot` version :

```
G N U P L O T
Version 5.0 patchlevel 6    last modified 2017-03-18

Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2017
Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others
```

And this its working perfectly in this version.

Quick Tip for anyone looking to compile gnuplot with the QT term support :

1. Install the `qt-sdk` package.
2. `configure` the gnuplot source with `--with-qt=4` to actually enable QT term support.

Comment: I just checked the ChangeLog and it is indeed fixed only since 5.0.6